# Roboelectric 2.2 error

Tags: robolectric

I am getting the following error with roboelectric 2.2

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createRobolectricClassLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createSdkEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:116)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$3.create(RobolectricTestRunner.java:279)
    at org.robolectric.EnvHolder.getSdkEnvironment(EnvHolder.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:277)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.access$100(RobolectricTestRunner.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I configured using the site http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/03/android-unit-testing-with-robolectric.html

I am using the android jar file in the application and the test project. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

yes, I had the same problem, `asm` version issue as @thoutisbeckers said. Try this:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
    compile ('org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0') {
        exclude module: 'asm'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like you're using version 1.7 of the JDK to compile and run your Robolectric tests. JDK 1.7 is incompatible with Robolectric and can result in issues similar to the one you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you. I will try with java6. Ofcourse, going back to java6 on mac is a total mess :(. Maybe I can just point to it with JAVA_HOME or something. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You likely have a dependency somewhere on an old version of `asm` (lower than version 4). Make sure you exclude it from the build path since Robolectric only work with 4 an up.

In my case it was a version of Guice that contributed it.